# what are good options to create a portable standard desktop GUI application

Tags: java

I want create a portable DeskTop Application with Graphical Possibility

I am Identifier with Swing,awt and Java FX

I think that i cant use awt because this don't work in all OS

but I don't khow what best option for my Application?

can I use both Swing and javaFx?

Is there other technology for create portable GUI Desktop Application ?

thank you

Comment: Take a look at [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) as well, the tookit created and used by Eclipse.

Comment: AWT works on all Java platforms. Swing based on AWT. What  do you mena with "portable": for portable devices or portable for diferent OS ?

Comment: my mean is portable for different OS

Answer (score 1):

Swing is probably your best bet. AWT has no benefits anymore - Swing has superceded it. JavaFX is also a good option. The only problem with JavaFX is its low adoptability compared to Swing. There are very few expericned people in JavaFX out there. But JavaFX can embed Swing components.

Swing is very mature, and has a huge amount of information on the web.

SWT is another option, but with SWT you need to learn the RCP framework from Eclipse and that can take a while. Also, SWT is fairly restricting in what you can do. With Swing you have complete freedom.

That's about it for Java that i can think of.

Comment: Do you really need RCP to build SWT applications? I know RCP/Eclipse uses SWT but I think an SWT application can theoratically be built outside the RCP framework. Although this might lead to a lot of fun with dependencies...

Comment: yeah you can but its not recommended

Comment: thank you , I don't khow what is RCP/Eclipse?! I use netbeanse for my work, is eclipse best than netbeanse , for use swt I should use eclipse. can I use SWT,Swing , JAVA FX together ?! PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: I would go with Swing because it is more straightforward. You can do Graphics/Animation or whatever you want in it. JavaFX probably can do the same, but you won't find much online help if you get stuck. Post a question on Swing on StackExchange and within 5 minutes you will have an answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a good GUI Framework for you JAVA Application.

AWT is totally outdated and was succeded by Swing.

You can use JavaFx and Swing together, for example, to integrate JavaFX in an old swing application.

An alternative would be to use SWT (like Eclipse).

Building nice looking GUIs in Java is quite a hard task. I would use JavaFX or SWT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google window builder available with eclipse. https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro Here are the details on how to install.